# jQuery like custom functions

Tags: javascript

I have been wondering how I can create functions like jQuery. For example: `$(ID).function()`

Where ID is the id of an HTML element, `$` is a function that return the document.getElementById reference of the element "ID" and function is a custom  javascript function.

I'm creating a little library which implements some functions. And I want to use that sintax without using jQuery.

Now, my questions are: how I can implement that? What is the name of the tecnique that allow that?

Edit:

What I want to do is this:

> HTMLElement.prototype.alertMe = function() {alert(this.value);}

Then, when I call `document.getElementById('html_input_id').alertMe()`, it must show an alertbox with the input value. But `HTMLElement.prototype` doesn't work in IE.

Comment: Why not get the jQuery source and look at it?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to create a plugin. I won't use jQuery at all.

Comment: Andre, I already tried object.prototype, but it doesn't work on IE

Comment: prototype-style inheritance definitely works on IE

Answer (score 1):

```
$ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, look, what you're asking has a lot of details and implications.  The code for jQuery is open source, you can read it for the details; you'd do well to find a good Javascript book as well, the the O'Reilly Definitive Guide.

`$` is just a character for names in JS, so as some of the other answers have shown, there's no reason you can't just write a function with that name:

```
var $ = function(args){...}
```

Since everyone and his brother uses that trick, you want to have a longer name as well, so you can mix things.

```
var EstebansLibrary = function(args){...}
var $ = EstebansLibrary; // make an alias
```

Since you end up doing different things with the entry point function, you need to know how JS uses arguments -- look up the `arguments` object.

You'll want to package this so that your internals don't pollute the namespace; you'll want some variant of the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth), which will make it something like

```
var EstebansLibrary = (function(){
    // process the arguments object
    // do stuff
    return {
       opname : implementation,...
    }
})();
```

And you'll eventually want to be prepared for inheritance and that means putting those functions into the `prototype` object.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, I'll consider those tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prototype to assign a new function to the Element prototype.

> Element.prototype.testFunction=function(str){alert(str)};

This would provide the function 'testFunction' to all HTML elements.

You can extend any base Object this way, i.e. Array, String etc.

This will work without any plugin at all - although that said I don't think it will work in IE. I believe libraries such as MooTools and jQquery create their own inheritance with DOM elements to ensure cross-browser compatibility, although don't quote me on that.